# Print "hello" if number of files in a directory is bigger than the number in first line of a file

Tags: command-line, bash

Write command line that prints hello if number of files in current directory is bigger than the number specified in first line of file check.

This works fine but i want a one command line. Any ideas?

```
firstline=$(head -1 check)
allfiles=$(ls | wc -l)
echo $allfiles  $firstline

if (($allfiles > $firstline)); then
     echo "hello"
else 
     echo "oh no"
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this one liner:

```bsh
files=( * ); [[ ${#files[@]} -gt $(head -1 check) ]] && echo 'hello' || echo 'oh no'
```

`files` array will contain the files of the current directory, so `${#files[@]}` shows the elements in the array i.e. number of files in the current directory.

The file `check` whose first line is a number is extracted by `head -1 check`.

Here is the expanded form :

Finally if number of files is greater than the number at the first line of `check` (`[[ ${#files[@]} -gt $(head -1 check) ]]`), `hello` is printed.

Here is the expanded form :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
files=( * )
if [[ ${#files[@]} -gt $(head -1 check) ]]; then
    echo 'hello'
else
    echo 'oh no'
fi
```

Comment: you are my Hero!!!

Comment: @MartinYeboah Glad i could help  :)